# getting a column from dataframe to anoter based on condition

Tags: python, pandas

i have a dataframe

```
name   class   target
ashe    2-5     rr
ashe    1-5     rt
vao     3-2     urr
vao     3-1     urr
cool    5-9     rur
```

and another dataframe

```
name   class   value
ashe    2-5     5
ashe    1-5     20
foal    8-8     66
vao     3-2     33
vao     3-1     5
cool    5-9     23
```

i want to create a dataframe that will be like :

```
name   class   target   value
ashe    2-5     rr      5
ashe    1-5     rt      20
vao     3-2     urr     33
vao     3-1     urr     5 
cool    5-9     rur     23
```

i need to get the valueس of df2["value"] where df1.name == df2.name and df1.class = df2.class , then add the result series to df1 as a new column
what can i do?

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
new_df = df1
new_df["value"] = df2["value"]
```

Something along those lines or [`pd.concat()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html)

Comment: they are not the same length

Comment: then `df2.iloc[:4,2]`

Comment: not my answer , i need to get the value of df2["value"] where df1.name == df2.name and df1.class = df2.class , then add the result series to df1 as a new column